# Check if date is in range -45min +45min using Doctrine DQL with Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I want to query my database using DQL and find out if there is any record in this table of mine wich collides with one that I'm about to insert, the thing is that I cannot insert records if the time column collides with them.

Each entity represents an Appointment so they have a duration of at least, 45min, and thats what I want my query to check. This is what I've come up with:

1. If every appointment has a duration of 45min, then I would have to check if there is already a record in the database in the range of (Appointment.time - 45min, Appointment.time)
2. Can't just make unique the time column and be happy because of the duration matter, we're better than that.

The code I have so far and that doesn't work is this :D

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT a FROM AcmeStuff\ApiBundle\Entity\Appointment a
                          WHERE a.time BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2
                          ORDER BY a.date DESC');
$query->setParameter(1, $appointment->getDate()->sub(new \DateInterval('PT45M')));
$query->setParameter(1, $appointment->getDate());
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction, feels like I'm far from it.

**EDIT:**

I'm not getting the records that I should be getting, what is the correct way to query for a range of dates using DQL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

you need to write it like this

```
createQuery('SELECT a FROM AcmeStuff\ApiBundle\Entity\Appointment a ....
```

Comment: Thanks! I just found that out! Forgot for a moment there I wasn't using regular sql, actually my problem is in the query, the "BETWEEN" part doest seem to work fine. Is this the way to go when it comes to fetch records in a range of dates?